# Tinkercad: amplify TMP36 signal with an opamp problem

Tags: 741-opamp

[image]

I want to amplify the TMP36 signal with a simple opamp, but the multimeter Vo shows no result. The same happens for other configuration.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Start with a proper schematic and not a cartoon or artists impression of your breadboard. Include all connections and all components. Also provide data sheet link to the op-amp and the sensor. BTW, if the op-amp is a 741 then forget it because it won't work.

Comment: @谢RenS:  Draw a schematic diagram of your circuit from the wiring diagram.  I think you will find at least one error.

Comment: Verify all terminal voltages will tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

### [image]
Solution

- Connect floating supply common grounds. Never assume.
- Consider the non-inverting solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnLsuv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Verify your assumptions with a meter.

Comment: Why do you think the V- is shared? V- on the topmost battery is connected to V+ on the bottom battery, just as you have illustrated.

Comment: mickey mouse schematics

Comment: @pipe is this better?

Comment: @pipe ?     ??????????????